# How To: Bootstrap3 Navbar - why is there a select list in my nav?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I've got this bootstrap3 navbar in my page, and the dang thing auto-spawns a drop-down-list for all the items in the navbar UL. How can I stop this?
[image]

My Navbar code:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container" style="margin-left: 0; margin-right: 0;">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="/"><img id="brand_logo_img_cc" src="/Content/images/logo.gif" alt="" style="width: 295px; height: 47px;" /></a>
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#mainHeaderNavbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="mainHeaderNavbar">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
        </div>
        <div id="mainHeaderNavbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse" aria-expanded="false" style="height: 1px;">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li class="dropdown"><a href="/">Home</a></li>
                <li class="dropdown"><a href="/"><!-- other generated links --></a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Since there's no drop-down-list in my code (aside from the nav drop down buttons), I assume this Go To drop-down is auto-generated by Bootstrap, but I don't know how to get rid of it.

Comment: I cant see anything in your code that would be doing this... and its certainly not something that is just "auto-generated" can you post your complete code and or a working plunkr

Comment: FYI: the blacked out parts in the image are just stuff that identifies the business (image and words), not code stuff.

Comment: It's the first code inside the <body> tag. And I got rid of any generated stuff in my header and pasted that exact code snippet in there... and it still happens.

Comment: Found the problem. One of our former developers put a custom.js in the solution that generates the damned thing. That was nasty.